Change shrink direction for ListView / ScrollablePositionedList
I'm building a chat page with ScrollablePositionedList.
To avoid new insertion change elements order cause trigger rebuild for every element completely, I have to set reverse: false
But I also need to keep showing bottom element when keyboard pop up, which rely on reverse: true
Currently I only have workaround like scroll_to_index + ListView, reverse: true + findChildIndexCallback to solve both problems, but It seems too tricky.
Is there any other way to control how ListView / ScrollablePositionedList padding? or somehow solve two problems naturally.
My widget structure is like
Scaffold(
    Column(
        Expanded(
            ListView.builder / ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
                    ...messages,
            ),
        ),
        TextField(),
    ), 
),

Thanks

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
